# I'm looking for a shortcut to view all opened windows for same application

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

So I want to reach to that view directly with one shortcut. To reach this I had to use CMD + tab then down arrow to android studio program to show me all opened projects so I can select which one. Is there a direct option to reach this directly? I know this option for CMD + ` to switch between same app windows but It doesn't work good for me I need overview first like this one to see clearly the opened projects and select.

[image: MAC OS android studio]

Comment: @SolarMike No. I'm asking for something else

Comment: Have you considered writing an Applescript or similar to do what you want?

Comment: Set one of your Hot Corners to "Application Windows", then all you need to do is slam the mouse into the corner.  Fitt's Law.

Comment: If you have a trackpad you can go to Settings -> trackpad -> trackpad gestures -> enable App Exposé with 3/4 finger swipe down (this is available on Macos 13.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the focus is in any windows of the app, press Ctrl + down arrow, and it will show all open windows of the app. You won't see the minimized windows, though.

Comment: Thank you!. That is what I was looking for. But Is there is a way to change the key that does that option? Instead of CTRL + down I make it. CMD + shift for example?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you can change it: Just go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and under "Mission Control", change the key assignment of "Application windows" by clicking on the key assignment and then pressing on your new key combination. But I think you can't assign cmd + shift only. You also need to add a key, since both cmd and shift are only modifier keys. By the way, if your computer has a trackpad, dragging down with three fingers also should do the same thing.

Comment: I just did it. Thank you so much for your help, Alper.